# Not able to run simple Servlet on tomcat server. getting HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class com.main.Hello error

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, classnotfound

When I try to run a simple servlet class on Tomcat Server it is giving this error.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class com.main.Hello

type Exception report
message Error instantiating servlet class com.main.Hello
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it 
from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class com.main.Hello
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.main.Hello
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.75 logs.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.75
```

I don't understand what is going wrong. I have checked everything I know. Mapped properly in XML. below is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>Web_Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.main.Hello</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

please let me know if anymore information is needed. and please help me in resolving this.

thank you.

Comment: Have you actually written the servlet file at com.main.Hello.java?

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.main.Hello` this message suggests there are problems with the WAR file and/or deployment procedure. `Tomcat` can't find the .class file.

Answer (score 0):

check your class path properly and make sure `web.xml` is exist into `WEB-INF` folder. then clean your project and run it.